CANopen Object Dictionary design with multiple idenctical nodes
I want to design a CANopen network. Let's assume I have a main node (controller), and 2 slave nodes and the slave nodes are simple units, they only need one object per node. For example the button nodes have an 'isPressed' object per node. How should I design the Object Dictionary so the main node can differentiate between the buttons?

I know the buttons should have different nodeId-s and that should (?) be used to differentiate between them.
It seems to me that i should make two object entries in the Object Dictionary and assign them to the buttons:



Object index
Name




0x2000
isPressed of Button1


0x2001
isPressed of Button2



But then what's the use of the nodeId anymore?
The other option is to have a single object in the OD:



Object index
Name




0x2000
isPressed of Button



And then use the nodeID to differentiate between the buttons. But based on the implementation of the stack I'm using (CANopenNode), it seems to be not possible.
Which one is the correct method of designing the OD?

Either method is technically fine and allowed in CANopen. In the first approach, you can have node 1 only implement object 2000h and node 2 only implement object 2001h since the other one will never be used. The downside: Both nodes will have to know what function they are and configure or use their Object Dictionary dynamically, or have different firmware versions dedicated to their function. This is sub-optimal.
In the real world you want as few different firmware versions as possible so your second suggestion is what most users will go for—nodes with the same function will have identical firmware and only the manager node will know about their function based on

their node ID
their data in the identity object 1018h and the device type entry 1000h
custom system configuration

In case you use SDO communication to poll the button data, the node ID is always part of the protocol so there is no ambiguity and you can easily read the same object from different nodes. It is not very efficient, though. In most cases you will map your input object to a TPDO and have it transmit when the data changes. As long as you use one of the first four TPDOs that are part of the so-called predefined connection set, the node ID is part of the so-called COB-ID (equal to the CAN message ID). The CAN message ID for the first TPDO, TPDO1, will be 180h+node ID, TPDO2 uses 280h+node ID and TPDO3/4 use 380h/480h+node ID. Both nodes, even when using only TPDO1, will transmit TPDO CAN messages with different message IDs. You will have to set up separate RPDOs in the manager node for the TPDOs you need to receive and there, you will have to map the data to different Object Dictionary entries, for example following the layout from your first suggestion. So the data from both buttons will end up in different places and you will have no ambiguity.
